# Voicing Into Closure? [segmentation, waveform and spectrogram form Praat]

Tags: phonetics, praat, acoustic-analysis

I'm wondering for how long the voicing persists into closure here, if at all. At about 50% into the closure I would say it's noise only from there on, nevermind F1. But what about the oscillations before that point?

[image: waveform and spectrogram of /p/ in "type of"]

Answer (score 4):

Your spectrogram is not clear. You should use a narrow-band spectrogram to see formants efficiently. So change your settings. To obtain this visualisation, you should use a small window length as it is indicated here: http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/Intro_3_2__Configuring_the_spectrogram.html

After that, if it appears harmonics with a high energy, so this segment is voiced. Like in these examples: https://www.krisyu.org/blog/supp-material-cantonese-creak-perception.html

Answer (score 1):

This is probably background noise. To check this, compare a section with no speech. For example, during closure of /p/ you can get very strong apparent "coarticulation" from preceding /a/ where the formants of /a/ are identifiable -- if there is an echo. You can't analyse noise with just a tiny snippet of a spectrogram, you need an actual acoustic wave sample of a full utterance.

Comment: Thank you. I am afraid that a section with no speech looks different; there is much more irregular noise. Also, there isn't much echo in the recording. And, most importantly, other word-final stop closures usually show some very obvious phonation but for about 20 m, not as in this example. For the reasons mentioned, I think it's some kind of phonation rather than just noise.